# Running Akka with Maven

Tags: scala, maven

When I try to use the Akka Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
    <artifactId>akka</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0-RC2</version>
</dependency>
```

I receive this error:

> Missing artifact com.typesafe.akka:akka:jar:2.2.0-RC2

Which dependency should I use for Akka with Scala version 2.10.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akka 2.2.0-RC2 should work fine with scala 2.10.1.

The dependency should look like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
    <artifactId>akka-actor_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0-RC2</version>
</dependency>
```

where akka-actor can be replaced by akka-remote etc..

You can also use the latest Scala 2.10.2 with Akka 2.2.0.